# Can I ice skate on toluene?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, phase-diagram, chemical-compounds

I thought about that can I ice skate on [toluene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toluene)?
We can ice skate on ice but can we do it on ice?

Please help me it would be helpful for me

Comment: Maybe as a non chemist I am missing something - I find this question bewildering because I don't know any property of toluene that might make it easy to skate on. If you detailed why you thought one might be able to do this, it might make the question a little less cryptic. Do you mean frozen toluene?

Comment: Liquid toluene being less dense than water, frozen is a given!

Comment: Also melting point being about -100 °C, it would be quite uncomfortable!

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Thanks. It would be better if the OP made this correction.

Comment: Yes, i mean frozen toluene

Comment: I think it will be probably more difficult. I do not say impossibile as it is a myth that water ice is melted by the pressure of the skater on blade but at least water can melt under pressure, which is not the case for toluene. Let me say that friction melts the toluene, likely the skater should experience something different as compared to water due to the various different properties at (or that can be) play, e. g. melting heat, surface tension. The only requisite is to have a liquid film. It should be possible to skate.

Comment: For clarity, OP means 'original poster', i.e. you, @H.Adam.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike stated in the comments, it is not a myth that ice "melts" under sharp skates. Water has a rare property of expanding in volume when frozen. Ice is a solid with a certain lattice structure that requires soecific orientation and distances between molecules. These requirements don't apply to liquid water and it so happens that molecules are packed closer together in liquid water.

The reverse is also true. When you put a high enough pressure on ice, such as by an edge of a sharp blade, the lattice structure of ice breaks down thus allowing water molecules to move freely and provide lubrication. Sharpening blades reduces friction, because a sharper edge creates a higher pressure on a smaller area.

Another error in the comments is that "the only requisite is to have a liquid film". This is obviously incorrect, because skating on a wet concrete floor woukd not work. The skates simply push the liquid out and contact the concrete directly. What is actually required for skating is a phase transition of the surface material from solid to liquid uder pressure ("melting"). Obviously "melting by friction" would not remove friction either.

I don't know if toluene expands on freezing, but it is unlikely, because it is a rare property. So it is unlikely that you could skate on frozen toluene, unless if by "skating" you mean "getting high", as toluene is an intoxicating substance. It also is poisonous, as toluene breaks down red blood cells, so skating on it in any sense of the word is not a good idea.

Comment: Just to add a little to this answer, slipperiness is one of many poorly understood properties of water ice, though to result from [premelting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premelting). Water has an unusually rich solid phase diagram, and toluene is very physically and chemically different, and whether you can skate on it depends not only on the crystal structure of toluene, but how it at a surface on the molecular level.